# Why use multiple arguments to log instead of interpolation?

Tags: python, logging, interpolation

Python's logging functions allow you to pass them multiple arguments that they can interpolate for you. So you have a choice:

```
logger.info("Something %s this way comes!" % "wicked")
```

or

```
logger.info("Something %s this way comes!", "wicked")
```

But why choose one over the other? Is it simply a matter of letting errors happen in the logger as opposed to in the program that's being logged, or is there something else to it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a matter of performance :

- When you do the interpolation in your code, this code will be executed each time you call the logger (event if the logger or the log level is not activated)
- When you let the logger do the interpolation, it will do the interpolation only if the logger and log level is activated.